# why there is a broken img on the webpage

Tags: html

I just started to learn html, and I am creating a self-intro webpage through github. 
Here is a question:
I opened the html file ( a webpage) on my computer, and it showed the picture perfectly, but when I opened the page through github, the img was broken. What's the problem here? 
Thanks very much

```
<!-- this is the code for the picture !-->
<div id="main">
    <div class="picture"><img src="/Users/shuai9532/Documents/img/IMG_1665.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is on your computer, not GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

You have an URL consisting of an absolute *path* (i.e. one that starts with a single `/`). It is resolved relative to the root of the current site.

When you open it locally, it resolves from the root of your file system.

When you open it through an HTTP server, it resolves from the root of the host.

The image does not exist on the Github hosted site (or, if it does, not in the same relative place).

Comment: do I just move the picture from the current folder to the github.io folder on my computer? Thanks

Comment: You also need to make sure that the URL is relative to the right place, that you commit the image, that you publish the image and that whatever mechanism you are using to see the rendered HTML on github is one that will support the rendering of images. (I don't recommend github webhosting as a means to learn HTML, I'd use a local webserver for that and leave git for version control).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using relative links which will work ONLY if the image's link is still valid after uploading it to the server (or Github in this case). I'm not sure about GitHub, but make sure the relative links are correct or alternatively try an ABSOLUTE LINK ( by hosting image on one of the free image hosting like imgur.com and getting its absolute link like https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mRR9.jpg for example. You can even try to place this image inside the **src** attribute to make sure that images can be accessed by that page on the server )

More about Absolute and Relative links can be found [here](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).